# List of attachments - JIRA REST API

Tags: jira

I am reading here about the REST API of JIRA:
http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id233354

I can see there are methods to post an attachment to an issue, as well as to get information about an attachment by it's ID. But I can not find a call that can provide me with a list of attachments for a specific issue.

So my question is: How is JIRA linking the attachments to the issues? How can I get a list of attachment ids for a specific issue?

Thanks :)

#### EDIT

Actually, if I make the call to get the issue information (full issue information) the attachments are there as a field. Thanks for reading anyway :)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Sorry I'm a new guy here, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the call to get the issue information (full issue information) the attachments are there as a field.

Comment: Note that the "Attachment" field must be part of the default screen for the issue or it won't get sent as part of the response. You can still see the attachments when viewing the issue in the browser even when the "Attachment" field is not part of the screen.